# No Scrolling when the Cursor is on the iFrame Area (Firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

I have a website with a centered iframe, which has a fixed height and width. So you cannot scroll within the iframe, but you can scroll the whole side.

*The Problem:* When I want to scroll the whole side, but I have my mouse over the area of the iframe, it doesn't work. I have to move the mouse to the side so its not over the iframe anymore. I only have this problem in Firefox.

CSS of the iFrame, body scroll is standard:

```
.frame{
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-384px;
    border:0;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: You say you can't scroll due to the fixed width and height, then you say you can scroll the 'whole side'? Could you clarify?

Comment: I uploaded an image: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg51/scaled.php?server=51&filename=framez.jpg&res=landing the white box is a iframe an it ist centered in the middle (no scroll inside the iframe). When i now scroll down the side with haven the curser in the area of the iframe(white box) i cannot scroll but if i move away from it, it works. I got this problem only in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your CSS `overflow` property.

```
.frame{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -384px;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: scroll; /* not necessary */
    position: absolute;
}
```